# Should a pointer be the same before and after adding to a unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, pointers, unique-ptr

I have a `std::vector` of `unique_ptr`s and I'm happy to have them manage the life cycle of those objects.

However I require storing other pointers to those objects for convenience. I know that once `unique_ptr` removes something, those other pointers will dangle. But I'm more concerned about the validity of those pointers before and after `unique_ptr` gets them.

I do not always create via `new` within the `unique_ptr` itself, for example I might pass `new Something` as a function parameter in which case the `unique_ptr` is using `move` on that pointer into itself inside the function.

But I might also `new Something` before I pass it into a function that then assigned it a `unique_ptr`.

Once an object is assigned to a `unique_ptr` I can get a pointer to it via `get()`. But can I always assume that this `get()` pointer points to the same place as the pointer initially obtained via `new` if the original pointer was created before the assignment to a `unique_ptr` ?

My assumption is Yes, and that even if the `vector` resizes and reallocates, the `unique_ptr` as well as any other pointers to the objects in memory remain the same.

Comment: More computery code, less humany text. :)

Comment: What I understood is that you're *sharing* pointers. Seems like it should better be done with `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: @MarkGarcia valid point, but I'm still curious about how a normal C-style pointer interacts in this way with the std smart pointers

Comment: `unique_ptr` doesn't change the pointer it owns. As others have mentioned. the description of what you want to do sounds like it pretty much may defeat the purpose of having a `unique_ptr` to the object.

Comment: @MarkGarcia  There is a difference between having more than one pointer to an object and having more than one _owning_ pointer. If it made no sense to have a normal non-owning pointer, then `unique_ptr` wouldn't have a `get()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a `std::unique_ptr<T>` holds a `pointer to T`, and it will not alter the value between initialization and later retrieval with `get()`

A common use of a `unique_ptr` is to assign one "parent" object ownership of a dynamically-allocated "subobject", in a similiar same way as:

```
struct A
{
    B b;
}

int main()
{
    A a = ...;
    B* p = &a.b;
}
```

In the above `b` is a true subobject of `A`.

Compare this to:

```
struct A
{
    unique_ptr<B> b = new B(...);
}

int main()
{
    A a = ...;
    B* p = a.b.get();
}
```

In the above `A` and `(*b)` have a similar relationship to the first example, except here the `B` object is allocated on the heap.  In both cases the destructor of A will destroy the "subobject".  This "on heap" subobject structure may be preferable in some cases, for example because `B` is a polymorphic base type, or to make `B` an optional/nullable subobject of `A`.

The advantage of using `unique_ptr` over a raw pointer to manage this ownership relationship is that it will automatically destroy it in `As` destructor, and it will automatically move construct and move assign it as part of A.

As usual, in both cases, you must be careful that the lifetime of any raw pointers to the subobject are enclosed by the lifetime of the owning object.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, you are correct, because `unique_ptr` does not copy the object; therefore, it has to point to the same address. However, once you give a pointer to a `unique_ptr` to own, you should not use that raw pointer any more, because the `unique_ptr` could be destroyed and deallocate the memory, and turn your raw pointer into a dangling pointer. Perhaps `shared_ptr` would be better for your situation.

Comment: -1: unique_ptr would be useless if you could not have other non-owning pointers or references to it's contents.

Comment: @DeadMG doesn't the name imply that it's supposed to be the only pointer to something? Or does the `unique` part mean it's just the only _owning_ pointer to something? It goes without saying of course that you can use pointers however you want as long as you're sure the `unique_ptr` isn't destroyed (removed from the `vector` in this case), but I didn't get the impression that that's what this question was about.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: It was the first sentence of the OP's second paragraph. How'd you miss that?

Comment: @NicolBolas miss what? I said what the OP can do, what I think he shouldn't do, and what I think he should do.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: You said "*I didn't get the impression that that's what this question was about.*" The first sentence of the second paragraph is "However I require storing other pointers to those objects for convenience." "other pointers" being the key phrase here.

Comment: @NicolBolas yeah, I thought the question was about whether or not a raw pointer given to `unique_ptr` in its constructor is still valid after the constructor exits, to which I answered "yes". "can I always assume that this `get()` pointer points to the same place as the pointer initially obtained via `new` if the original pointer was created before the assignment to a `unique_ptr`?"

Comment: You answered the question fine, thanks. I think the argument made by @NicolBolas refers to the extra advice you gave in your answer which does not directly relate to my question, advice which is somewhat subjective and contrary to the stated use case that Nicol mentions.